# Parse date/time in the format 2017-05-16T19:00:00.451-0400 with Python

Tags: python-3.x, date, parsing

I've following string representing date/time:

```
my_datetime = "2017-05-16T19:00:00.451-0400"
```

With

```
datetime.strptime(my_datetime[:19], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

I get

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 16, 19, 0)
```

However, I don't understand what the `451-0400` part means and if there is better way to parse this string.

Comment: Microseconds and a timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have microseconds and a timezone offset. You can parse the first with `%f`, and the latter with `%z`, provided you use Python 3.2 or newer:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(my_datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 16, 19, 0, 0, 451000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000)))
```